# PYTHON: how to make inner function return one value at a time and depending on outer function's conditional decide whether to run or stop?

Tags: python, recursion, iteration, yield-return

I'm trying to come up with a way to write efficient permutations for a problem I'm trying to solve. I've looked all through both NumPy's and SymPy's documentation and can't find anything that helps with what I know.

**What I need:** I want to create a selective permutation function that, rather than returning all possible permutations, simply returns a single permutation, one by one.

**General idea of the process:** outer function calls my selective permutation function and this function returns ONE value at a time for the outer function to evaluate. If it passes the outer function's conditional statement then we are done, otherwise, it computes the inner function again for the next value and so on.

I've read on implementing yield instead but I'm not sure how to do it in this case.

If anyone has any advice on how to **return one value at a time and depending on outer conditional decide whether to run or stop** I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: have you considered the inner function to have a flag that determines whether to return something or not. Based on the flag, you can decide whether to send something or not.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "depending on outer conditional". Are you talking about another loop in the same function? Or do you mean in the calling context, or just what? It would help to show *some* code that you tried, even if it doesn't work, as long as it illustrates the problem.

Comment: Why bother having the inner function decide whether to yield a value or not? Why not just have the outer function _stop calling it_? You can make a function with the `yield` keyword, have a loop iterate through it, and then break out of that loop whenever appropriate.

Comment: Maybe [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) is what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Python's `itertools.permutations` already does this -

```py
from itertools import permutations

for p in permutations("abcd", 2):
  print(p)
  if p == ("b","c"):
    break

print("done")
```

```
('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('a', 'd')
('b', 'a')
('b', 'c')
done
```

This is because `itertools.permutations` returns a sort of lazy generator rather than computing all permutations up front.

```py
print(permutations("abcd", 2))
# <itertools.permutations object at 0x7f26ebd0bf40>
```

---

If you want *all* permutations, you would have to collect them in a `list` -

```py
print(list(permutations("abcd", 2)))
# [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'a'), ('d', 'b'), ('d', 'c')]
```

---

Here's what that might look like in a program

```py
def solve (values, size, check):
  for p in permutations(values, size):
    if (check(p)):
      return p

answer = \
  solve \
    ( [ 5, 3, 9, -4, 7 ]     # nums to check
    , 3                      # permutation size
    , lambda p: sum(p) == 10 # find permutation that adds to 10
    )

print(answer)
# (5, 9, -4)
```

And the answer checks out: `5 + 9 + -4` is equal to `10`!

Comment: And don't forget `itertools.permutations()` friends `product()`, `combinations()`, and `combinations_with_replacement()` (because sometimes people say permutations but really mean one of the others).

Comment: but what if I'm trying to do permutations in decreasing order? because i remember that i couldnt figure out how to do that with itertools permutations.

i need it in decreasing order because i need to find the first permutation that passes the conditional statement and so the search is decreased if i go from highest permutation to lowest

Comment: @cosmiccat if you want to generate the permutations in a different order, you can always write your own function. Learn about Python's built-in generators and use a `yield` expression to effectively pause a function

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly straight forward to do:

```
def innerFunction(your_inputs):
   #Generate Permutations & combinations
   for permutation in all_permutations:
       yield permutation

def OuterFunction():
    for permutation in innerFunction():
          if condition:
              break;
```

Comment: you are calling the `innerFunction()` without an argument while you defined the `innerFunction()` with an argument. Do you want to revisit the implementation?